# How to click on a button inside a popup as per the html through SeleniumWebdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I try to click in a button like imagen.

not working using class or xpath

this is the button
[image]

this is the inspect from this button.
[image]

this is the code trying to click on the button:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[10]/button")).click();
```

this is the xpath from the  before:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[10]"));
```

please could someone help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

Every simple change in the page will cause your code to stop functioning, try to always make use of *class* or *id* and navigate to it's siblings/parent nodes.

You can do that in 2 ways

1.By using CssSelector (Right click on the Element in DevTools -> Copy -> Copy Selector)

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("CopiedText")).Click()
```

2.By using XPath and accessing it through it's parent (Example for your case)

```
driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='advertising-layer']/button")).Click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the similar issue while accessing a button in a dialog box. I tried with XPath, id, it didn't work but it worked with **CSS selector**.
By using CSS selector I made the selenium webdriver to click on a button, pick a value from the drop-down in the dialog box, type a value in the text box.
I am not sure why exactly it worked with CSS selector and not with XPath. I'd be grateful if someone has a description for this.

If you want to get CSS selector of a particular element follow the below steps

- Open the application in Firefox
- open Inspect element, and in the inspector ( the place where you see the HTML code)
- Select the element in the page to view the particular code for the inspector by using this button [image]
- right click on the highlighted part of the code and hover on copy, you will find CSS selector

Let me know if this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to invoke `click()` on the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/div[@class='advertising-mask']//button"))).click();
```